# Calories consumed based on the number of items and type of food eaten

Tags: c++

Write a program that asks the user to input how many prosperity burgers (either single or double patty), twisted fries, drinks and 3 other available menus from McDonalds that he or she actually ate and then reports how many calories were consumed. At the end of your program, you need to display some wish for CNY. For example: “Happy Chinese New Year to those who celebrate it!!”. Format your calory readings in fixed-point notation, with two decimal places of precision, and be sure the decimal point is always displayed.
**Your 3 additional available menus could be any menus that you want to consider in your program.

Menu

1. Beef Prosperity Burger
2. Double Beef Prosperity Burger
3. 6pcs Chicken McNuggets
4. Ayam Goreng McD Spicy
5. OREO McFlurry

Calories

1. Beef Prosperity Burger - 490kcal, Twister Fries - 450kcal, Mcfizz - 250kcal
2. Double Beef Prosperity Burger - 802kcal, Twister Fries - 450kcal, Mcfizz - 250kcal
3. 6pcs Chicken McNuggets - 254kcal
4. Ayam Goreng McD Spicy - 572kcal
5. OREO McFlurry - 304kcal

```
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double Beef Prosperity Burger Set, Double Beef Prosperity Burger Set, Chicken McNuggets, Ayam Goreng McD Spicy, OREO McFlurry;
    
    //Get the amount of each item eaten.
    cout << "Enter the number of items consumed for Beef Prosperity Burger Set: ";
    cin >> Beef Prosperity Burger Set;
    cout << "Enter the number of items consumed for Double Beef Prosperity Burger Set: ";
    cin >> Double Beef Prosperity Burger Set;
    cout << "Enter the number of items consumed for Chicken McNuggets: ";
    cin >> Chicken McNuggets;
    cout << "Enter the number of items consumed for Ayam Goreng McD Spicy: ";
    cin >> Ayam Goreng McD Spicy;
    cout << "Enter the number of items consumed for OREO McFlurry: ";
    cin >> OREO McFlurry;
    
    //Calculate the total number of calories consumed.
    int Menu1 = 1190.00 kcal, Menu2 = 1502.00 kcal, Menu3 = 254.00 kcal, Menu4 = 572.00 kcal, Menu5 = 304.00 kcal;
    
    totalCalories = (Beef Prosperity Burger Set)*Menu1 + (Double Beef Prosperity Burger Set)*Menu2 + (Chicken McNuggets)*Menu3 + (Ayam Goreng McD Spicy)*Menu4 + (OREO McFlurry)*Menu5
    
    // Display the total calories consumed.
    cout << "\nCalories Consumed\n";
    cout << "-------------\n";
    cout << setprecision(6) << fixed;
    cout << "Total calories eaten today = " << setw(2) << totalCalories << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

They said I didn't declare the "Beef Prosperity Burger Set, Double Beef Prosperity Burger Set, Chicken McNuggets, Ayam Goreng McD Spicy, OREO McFlurry". Explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks~

Comment: you can't have spaces in variable names, you can't/don't need to put `kcal` on the end of your numbers either

Comment: As an advanced feature (not recommended for beginners), it is possible in C++ to have custom suffix with literals. So you could write something like `Energy Menu1 = 1190.00_kcal` (note the underscore). For your case, I don't think it makes sense to have `int` variables to store values which are floating point numbers; use `double` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable name shouldn't contain spaces

According to a rule to declare varaible name in C++

- Variable name must begin with letter or underscore.
- It should not start with numbers
- It should not contain spaces
- No special symbols are allowed other than underscore.

It must be declared as

```
BeefProsperityBurgerSet
```

or

```
Beef_Prosperity_Burger_Set
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but I can't seem to get the values to 2 decimal places. Could you help me?

`cout << setprecision(6) << fixed;`

This is what I used

Comment: I'll look into it